KeyBindings on any other level than "Window"
I created a very simple test program to try to understand KeyBinding in WPF, but it's not working the way I expect it, in fact it doesn't work at all in most of the cases. Maybe you can point out what I'm doing wrong or what is not supposed to work.
I have a DelegateCommand or RelayCommand class (or whatever it is called in your case), that is implementing ICommand and takes an Action, that is supposed to be called, when the ICommand is executed.
Then I created a simple view model that only contains three commands (for the sake of simplicity my example code does only show one of the commands, the other commands are for Ctrl-B and Ctrl+C.
Public Class MainViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase

    Private _keyBindingCommandCtrlA As ICommand = New DelegateCommand(AddressOf Me.KeyBindingCtrlAFired)

    Private Sub KeyBindingCtrlAFired(obj As Object)
        MessageBox.Show("Ctrl+A")
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property KeyBindingCommandCtrlA As ICommand
        Get
            Return _keyBindingCommandCtrlA
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Then I created two custom controls "Level1" and "Level2".
"Level2" just contains a defined KeyBinding for Ctrl+C like this:
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding KeyBindingCommandCtrlC}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>

"Level1" contains a defined KeyBinding for Ctrl+B and the "Level2" control (not shown in the example):
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="B" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding KeyBindingCommandCtrlB}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>

My main window contains a reference to the view model, a KeyBinding for Ctrl+A and it contains the "Level1" control (not shown in the example).
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="A" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding KeyBindingCommandCtrlA}" />
</Window.InputBindings>

When I run this example program I would have expected that all three KeyBindings work, so, when I press Ctrl+A, Ctrl+B or Ctrl+C, I'd see a message box telling me Ctrl+A, Ctrl+B or Ctrl+C.
But only Ctrl+A works. when pressing Ctrl+B or Ctrl+C nothing happens.
Then I tried something else. I removed the KeyBindings in "Level1" and "Level2" and added a KeyBinding for Ctrl+B directly to the "Level1" control in my main window like this:
<local:Level1Control>
    <local:Level1Control.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="B" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding KeyBindingCommandCtrlB}" />
    </local:Level1Control.InputBindings>
</local:Level1Control>

But that didn't help either, when pressing Ctrl+B nothing happens.
So, how do I get KeyBindings to work, when they're not defined at Window level?

Keyboard input is only sent to a UIElement if this element or a child element is focused.
The element that defines adds an InputBinding to UIElement.InputBindings is registered as input scope and is able to handle input for all its child element (only the child elements).
If you want the key binding to work globally (in the scope of the current visual root e.g. Window) you must register all key gestures at the visual root, in your case it's the main window. Usually, the focus is always within the scope of the visual root.
If you want to register with a different scope, like your UserControl, then you must know that the key gestures are only handled when the focus is within this scope (the UserControl or one of its children).
For example, adding a TextBox to your UserControl (note, TextBox will override your Ctrl+A gesture) allows the user to transition the focus to the key gesture scope of the UserControl by clicking on the child element. Now key gestures are sent to the focused scope where it can be handled.
The idea behind this behavior is to allow multiple input gesture scopes. For example, when a TextBox has focus, Ctrl+A is selecting all its contained text. But outside the TextBox Ctrl+A can execute a different action.
If you want to listen to a key gesture globally (e.g. on the root Window) but want to handle it in a different scope you can forward the key gesture using routed events:
MainWindow.xaml.cs
Use routed commands to register all key gestures with the root Window.
Forward the routed command using a tunneling routed event:
C#
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static RoutedEvent CtrlAEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(nameof(CtrlAEvent), RoutingStrategy.Tunnel, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MainWindow));
  public static RoutedCommand CtrlACommand;

  static MainWindow()
  {
    var crlAKeyGesture = new KeyGesture(Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control);
    MainWindow.CtrlACommand = new RoutedCommand(nameof(MainWindow.CtrlACommand), typeof(MainWindow));
    MainWindow.CtrlACommand.InputGestures.Add(crlAKeyGesture);
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new TestViewModel();
    var ctrlACommandBinding = new CommandBinding(MainWindow.CtrlACommand, ExecutedCtrlACommand, CanExecuteCtrlACommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(ctrlACommandBinding);
  }

  private void CanExecuteCtrlACommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => e.CanExecute = true;

  private void ExecutedCtrlACommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.CtrlAEvent, this));
}

VB.NET
Public Partial Class MainWindow
    Inherits Window

    Public Shared CtrlAEvent As RoutedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(NameOf(CtrlAEvent), RoutingStrategy.Tunnel, GetType(RoutedEventHandler), GetType(MainWindow))
    Public Shared CtrlACommand As RoutedCommand

    Private Shared Sub New()
        Dim crlAKeyGesture = New KeyGesture(Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control)
        MainWindow.CtrlACommand = New RoutedCommand(NameOf(MainWindow.CtrlACommand), GetType(MainWindow))
        MainWindow.CtrlACommand.InputGestures.Add(crlAKeyGesture)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.DataContext = New TestViewModel()
        Dim ctrlACommandBinding = New CommandBinding(MainWindow.CtrlACommand, AddressOf ExecutedCtrlACommand, AddressOf CanExecuteCtrlACommand)
        Me.CommandBindings.Add(ctrlACommandBinding)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CanExecuteCtrlACommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs)
        e.CanExecute = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExecutedCtrlACommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
        Return [RaiseEvent](New RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.CtrlAEvent, Me))
    End Sub
End Class

MainWindow.xaml
<Window>
  <KeyGestureUserControl />
</Window>

KeyGestureUserControl.xaml.cs
Listen to the routed event raised by the root Window as response to the key gesture.
Listen globally by registering a class handler.
Or register for a particular instance e.g. by using Window.GetWindow to get the parent Window instance:
C#
public partial class KeyGestureUserControl : UserControl
{
  public KeyGestureUserControl()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
    parentWindow.AddHandler(MainWindow.CtrlAEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnKeyGestureExecuted));
  }

  private void OnCtrlAKeyGestureExecuted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
  }
}

VB.NET
Public Partial Class UserControl1
    Inherits UserControl

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.Loaded += AddressOf OnLoaded
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnLoaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim parentWindow As Window = Window.GetWindow(Me)
        parentWindow.[AddHandler](MainWindow.CtrlAEvent, New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf OnKeyGestureExecuted))
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnKeyGestureExecuted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
    End Sub
End Class

KeyGestureUserControl.xaml
<UserControl>
</UserControl>


Thank you for this answer. My problem probably is, that my UserControl doesn't contain any element that can get focus. I'll try to change my example, and hopefully it works like expected after that.

If your UserControl doesn't have any focusable element then it doesn't make sense that it handles input gesture that require to be directed to an element (focus). Maybe you just should handle the keyboard input at root level e.g. MainWindow? Or why do you want to handle key gestures on an element that doesn't accept keyboard input in the first place?
